# JPA-JPQL query to fetch child entity field with all parent entity fields

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have below requirement to implement in `JPQL` but couldn't able to do it. Please help me here.

I have parent entity `Task` and two child entities `MoveTask` and `PickTask`.

These looks like below.

```
@Entity
class Task{
    String taskId;
    String taskName;
    String taskDesc;
}

class MoveTask extends Task{
    String moveType;
}


class PickTask extends Task{
    String taskType;
}
```

The existing `JPQL` Query:

```
String Query="SELECT task.taskId,task.taskName,task.taskDesc FROM TASK";
```

As per my new requirement I need to get the **taskType** field which is there in `PickTask`.

If I change the query as below it is not fetching the moveTaks records from db.

```
String newQuery="SELECT task.taskId,task.taskName,task.taskDesc,task.taskType FROM PickTask"
```

I want to fetch all records from db but the above one fetching `PickTask` Type only.

Appreciate your help here.

Comment: I would recommend you that you try to eliminate all the posible variables and try to test something like this if you are using NetBeans https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/test_jpql_with_netbeans_ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by using LEFT JOIN in JPQL.

The query as given below.

```
SELECT task.taskId,task.taskName,task.taskDesc,pickTask.taskType FROM Task task LEFT JOIN PickTask pickTask on (task.taskId=pickTask.taskId);**
```

Thank you @fangdi your idea helps me to think differently and fix this.

Answer (score 0):

your design is a bit inefficient. Why don't you put another enum field to Task instead of making 2 more entities? Then your entity will be like:

```
@Entity
class Task{

String taskId;
String taskName;
String taskDesc;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
TaskType taskType;
}
```

your JPQL query would be very simple:

```
"SELECT T FROM TASK T WHERE T.taskType = 'PICK'"
```

Comment: Sorry I can't change the standard entity Task. I can make only changes to MoveTask entity.

Comment: If that's the case you could try to use JOIN query. But I don't recommend the design like this, it is very hard to extend and test in the future.

Answer (score 0):

your JPQL query would be very simple:

```
  "SELECT T FROM Task T WHERE T.taskType != null"
```

Comment: I'm getting an error since the variable taskType is not defined in the Task entity.

Comment: The error is **The state field path 'task.taskType' cannot be resolved to a valid type**

Comment: the error related to the case sensitivity in Jpql. Your entity don't persist to any database?

Comment: Hi, how are you testing your jpql query?